# Why do we use the \n\r in the websocket handshake response?

Tags: http, tcp, websocket, handshake

Why do we use the `\r\n` in the HTTP headers for JS WebSocket handshake `response` and two times `\r\n\r\n` at the end, but not in handshake `request`? Is it possible to do the handshake response without adding the `\r\n`?

Are the `\r\n` also used in TCP sockets or is it only used for JS WebSocket?

For example:

```
"Upgrade: something\r\n".
"Connection: something\r\n".
// ...
"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: something\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: \r\n (CRLF), not \n\r (order matters!).. anyway, consider it is `\r\n<blankline>\r\n` -- the blank like separates the HEADERS from the BODY. This is shaped per the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do we use the \n\r in HTTP headers for JS WebSocket handshake response ...

The initial Websocket handshake is HTTP. So the message format used is defined in the HTTP specification. HTTP itself has this idea from earlier standards like RFC 821 (format of mail) which again got this from older stuff - let's just say it evolved that way similar to how languages evolved. One might have done this differently but now it is like this.

The important part is that all use it the same way and understand it the same way, which includes understanding that it is neither `\n\r` as you said, not `\n` as commonly used, but `\r\n`.

> Are the \n\r is also used in TCP socket or no it is only used for JS WebSocket?

TCP is an octet stream only where the different transferred bytes have no specific meaning at the level of TCP. Application layer protocols like HTTP or WebSockets add a meaning to the bytes and thus define a structure of the transferred data. Ultimately WebSockets use TCP sockets for the transport of the messages, i.e. WebSockets essentially define structured messages and how they get serialized as bytes in order to be transferred within the data stream TCP provides.

Comment: So, its just to represent the separate each header line of the HTTP headers and add the new lines at the application layer in the places or `\r\n`?

Comment: @SunnyKhan: I'm not sure how to understand the comment. `\r\n` is used as the line end inside the HTTP header and and additional `\r\n` (i.e. empty line) is used to signal end of the HTTP header. See [RFC 2616 section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4) for the relevant definition.

Comment: Newer RFC saying the same thing: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3 (2616 was split into multiple RFCs that go into more detail..)

Comment: @user2864740: this is a very basic requirement which you can already find in HTTP/1.0 (RFC 1945) and even in RFC 821 (Mail).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich No counter argument: simply providing another RFC link :)

Answer (score 3):

The initial WebSocket handshake request is a standard HTTP upgrade request.  HTTP uses CRLF (which can be represented using the `\r\n` escape sequence in many languages, including C and C++) to terminate each line in a message's header, and uses 2 CRLFs to separate a message's headers from its body.  You must follow the HTTP spec when formatting the initial handshake.

Read [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for the WebSocket protocol spec, this is all covered in it.

Comment: So, its just to represent the separate each header line of the HTTP headers and add the new lines at the application layer in the places or `\r\n`?

Comment: @SunnyKhan See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3 for the format of an HTTP request; each header field ends in a CRLF and there is a CRLF between the last header and the body.